# Redirect to another UserControl using Popup in WPF

Tags: c#

I am using WPF application and I want to display popup and when I Click on OK button then Popup should close and it should display UserControl. Hope my question is clear to all.

Comment: Just use `MessageBox.Show("Message")` to show a popup message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088465/wpf-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change userControl by code

```
Panel myPanel = new Panel();    
LoginPage ctlLoginPage = new LoginPage();
HomePage ctlHomePage = new HomePage();

//add the loginpage to the panel first
myPanel.Controls.Add(ctlLoginPage);

...do stuff...

//remove whatever control is currently in the Panel
myPanel.Controls.Clear();
//add the other control, the HomePage control instead now
myPanel.Controls.Add(ctlHomePage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have wrote the code like above you have mentioned. When First time popup is opened and I press OK button then it display respective usercontrol.but when second time Popup is opened then usercontrol didn't display. I am using window form to display the popup. by using and my code is :                                                     PopupWindow PW = new PopupWindow();
PW.SetParent(this);
PW.ShowDialog();

Comment: @Avinash maybe you should add PW.Dispose(); at the end of your code

Comment: i am using  PW.Dispose(); but it is showing error : does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' and no extension method 'Dispose' accepting a first argument of type